# How does this for loop array works?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I just learn about array today but I don't actually understand this code I'm learning.

```
let units = [1, 10, 100, 1000, 20];

for(let i = 0; i < units.length; i += 1){
    console.log(units[i]);
}
```

How would `console.log(units[i]);` return `1`, `10`, `100`, `1000`, `20` and not `5`?

Could you guys explain to me the way I will actually understand this?

Comment: `units[i]` accesses the element of the array at index `i`, so, if `i=0` it gives `1`, if `i=1` it gives `10`, if `i=2` it gives `100` and so on

Comment: What makes you think there should be a `5` output, since there's no `5` in your source array (`units`)?

Comment: You may find this MDN guide to arrays useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays

Comment: Because when I wrote console.log(i), there will be 5 output that is 0,1,2,3,4. I just don't understand how would ```console.log(units[i])``` works

Comment: When you `console.log(i)`, you're outputting the value of `i` which, in this case, will be a number from `0` to `4`. When you access array by index, which is what the brackets at the end of the variable name do, you're saying, 'give me the one specific value of the array at position number `i`'. If `i` is `0`, then it will return `1` as that's the first element of the array. When `i` is `1`, the value will be `10`, then `2` is `100` and so on until the end of the array.

Comment: You may also find it useful to type the word `debugger;` at the start of your code. When you then run it in the browser the code will proceed line by line, as you click through it, and you can see the values of each variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are both declaring that a variable `units` exists and you are putting elements in the array with your statement

```js
let units = [1, 10, 100, 1000, 20];
```

This has created an array with 5 elements; array elements are numbered (indexed) starting at *zero*:

```
| 1 | 10 | 100 | 1000 | 20 |     // array with elements in it
  0   1    2     3      4        // positions of elements
```

— the first element in the array is at position 0
that is, the item at `units[0]` is `1`, the item at `units[1]` is `10`, etc.

Now you start your loop, using the variable `i` as a number to use as an *index* into the array.

When `i === 0` then `units[i]` is asking for the element at position `units[0]`, which is 1,
when `i === 1` then `units[i]` is asking for the element at position `units[1]`, which is 10,
and so on.

So when you say `console.log(units[i]);` you are *not* printing the value of `i`; you are getting the element in the array `units` that is *at* position `i` in the array and printing *that*.
`console.log(units[i])` when `i === 3` gets the item *in the array* at position 3, which is `1000`, so it prints 1000.

Answer (score 1):

`units` is an array.

`units[0]` gets you the first item in the array (1). `units[1]` gets you the next item in the array (10). and so on.

So as `i` is incremented with each loop iteration, you get the corresponding item from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Just for your information.

This below is the initialization of list of numbers in a variable `units`

`let units = [1, 10, 100, 1000, 20];`

Now the loop begin.

`for()` is the loop.

Where 1st params `let i=0` tell the starting point of the array.

2nd params `i<units.length` defined the length of array where the loop needs to be end

3rs params tell the index need to be increment each time the loop executed.
For eg: when index `i` is 0, then value `units[i] = 1`. After its execution the value of index `i` is incremented by 1 due to `i++` as third param of `for()` loop.

The loop will continue until it meets the value of last index defined in second params that is `i<units.length`

```
for(let i = 0; i < units.length; i += 1){
    console.log(units[i]);
}
```

I hope it made you clear.